# sfValidatorDoctrineUnique and sha1 in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sha1

In **User.class.php** i have:

```
$this->setCode(sha1($this->getPassword()));
```

This is ok. In register form i would like use **sfValidatorDoctrineUnique**.

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model'=>'User', 'column'=>'code')));
```

But this doesnt work. This check password from form without sha1 and from database with sha1. I use sfValidatorDoctrineUnique also for email (without sha1) and this working ok.
How can i fix it? I use Symfony 1.4.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the hell would you check if the password is unique? this makes totally no sense

UPD: For creating an own validator create a /lib/valdator/sfValidatorDoctrineFoobar.class.php

```
<?php

class sfValidatorDoctrineFoobar extends sfValidatorBase
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    $this->addMessage('invalid_record', 'Unable to find the related record');
  }

  protected function doClean($value){
    $status = $this->getCodeStatus($value);
    if ($status == 1){
     throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'Code is invalid', array('value' => 'invalid code'));
    }

    if ($status == 2){
     throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'Code allready used', array('value' => 'used'));
    }

    return $value;
  }

  protected function getCodeStatus($value){
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Code c');
    $q->select('c.hash, c.used');
    $q->addWhere('c.hash = ?', $value);

    $result = $q->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    if (!$result) return 1;
    if ($result['used'] == 1) return 2;
    return false;
  }
}
```

just to show you an example.. you'll have to change the code to your needs ;)

Comment: then add some more entropy please :-) Something like $this->setCode(sha1($this->getPassword().$this->getId().$this->getUsername().time()));

Comment: very, very thanks, but how can i call this method in UserForm.class.php?

Comment: i have error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has a built in option for hashing your passwords I think that you should use that. You can read about it here: [sfGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin). If I were you I would be using the [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) in tandem with the [sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin). I was using that and it took care of all those problems.

Comment: i would like this also for CODE, not only for password

Comment: Then you should write a custom validator.

Comment: Have you tried to check out the symfony website? The answer is there. http://www.symfony-project.org/